# How to find the deadlock in ASP.Net Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, c#-2.0, asp.net-2.0

I am using .Net 2.0 and my site seems to reach the deadlock state at certain period. It stops working until I recycle the application pool or change something in web.config file. I think deadlock is causing this issue.

I am wondering if there is any tool to debug/check the site to find the code that could be causing the deadlock.

Right now I had to set recycling interval to 10 minutes which is really bad but it is the only way to solve the problem and there is a lot of codes on the site and I need to find the problem. If I use DOS attack tool, can I find the page/code block that is causing this issue? If I can, what is the best tool to test it?

Cheers!

**EDIT**
I tried to check the Event Logs and found the following warning. I don't know if it is issue will keep digging now.
Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: Request timed out.

Comment: This series of videos from Channel 9 covers this (and closely related topics): "[.NET Debugging for the Production Environment](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/-NET-Debugging-Stater-Kit-for-the-Production-Environment/Diagnosing-Application-Issues-01)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would attach visual studio to IIS and break the debugger when a deadlock occurs. You can then inspect the call stack of the running threads.

Code Project has a [nice article on how to do IIS remote debugging](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38132/Remote-IIS-Debugging-Debug-your-ASP-NET-Applicatio).

Of course, you can very well set up up a test machine with a local IIS and local Visual Studio .NET and do this without the need to remotely debug.

Comment: I tried to attach Visual Studio to IIS process but it said "Unable to attach to the process. The components for the 64-bit debugger are not registered. Please repair your Visual Studio 2008 Remote Debugger installation via 'Add or Remove Programs". It seems we have to ask our hosting facility to upgrade Visual Studio on server.

Comment: @JonasT I would rather set up a local machine (VMware) to mimic the live system, first. Only if this does not work, try to go to the live system.

Comment: I finally found the problem. It was the legacy code that was using static funciton of static class. When there are the number of visitors grow on the site, this happens. After I changed that code to use instance rather than static, the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

- Check the event log
- Turn on [Health Monitoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb398933(v=vs.140))

Answer (score 1):

If you use the 'Failed Request Tracing' and it'll produce a nice output which will then tell you what is causing the error, down to the module level. This will then give you the first step into where it's breaking down.

Have a read of this article on iis.net → [Troubleshooting Failed Requests Using Tracing in IIS 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis)

Comment: Thanks. I will try it as soon as I get on the server.